# Get attachments url to the list to another field in same list before saving the new item Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, attachments

I am having a list in my Sharepoint 2010 site. In that list I have some fields I want to attach some files to each new entry made and at the same time I want to store the URL of the file which is being attached to another column when the new item is being saved.

The URL is to be used for accessing the attached file in that list so I need to store the URL of the attached files as the path of attached file after the new item is saved.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create an event receiver that will do this. You can use the ItemAdded and the ItemUpdated events. Once an item is created or updated, it will go out and find the attachments and insert them into another field called "AttachmentUrls" or something of that nature. This is somewhat pseudocode, so the syntax needs to be checked.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    var attachmentfolder = properties.ListItem.ParentList.RootFolder.SubFolders["Attachments"].
                           SubFolders[properties.ListItem.ID.ToString()];
    foreach(file in attachmentfolder.Files){
    properties.ListItem["AttachmentURLs"] += file.Url;
    }
    properties.ListItem.Update();
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
}
```

Comment: It is showing "The type or namsespace name 'file' could not be found(are ypu missing a using directives or aasembly refernce)"

Comment: its pseudocode, sorry. it's not all syntactically correct, this should point you in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Using Designer Workflow on `item create`:

1. Call a REST query with the current item id:
   `lists/getbytitle('Custom%20List')/items(1)/attachmentfiles`
2. Loop through each attachment and add the url of it in multiline text column in the same list.
3. Send the email with the column in it.

Comment: Can you please brief out your steps, it will be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: You can update your answer instead of commenting. It will reach larger audience :)